# Is it possible to restore Nuget packages with a Xamarin.iOS build using TFS online?

Tags: macos, xamarin.ios, azure-devops, tfsbuild

I am trying to automate my build process for my `Xamarin.iOS` application. I have managed to get a `Xamarin.Android` and `UWP` build working find on my on site Windows build agent.

I am now trying to build a `Xamarin.iOS` application using my On Site Mac build agent.

I have added the Restore Nuget packages as the first step in this build definition but keep getting the error:

> MSBuild auto-detection: using msbuild version '4.0' from
>   '/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.2.3/lib/mono/4.5'.
>   MsBuild.exe does not exist at
>   '/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.2.3/lib/mono/4.5/msbuild.exe'.
>   Error: /usr/local/bin/nuget failed with return code: 1 Return code: 1

But I'm not sure what it's trying to do here at the nuget installer stage.

So is this possible to do?

Comment: Are you restoring the solution file in the "Restore Nuget Packages" step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a known issue with nuget restore command on non-Windows operating systems:

> Restore - Restore works with packages.config and project.json files
> but will not yet work with *.sln solution files

So you can try to update the "Restore Nuget Packages" step to restore the packages.config file instead of solution file. If it still does not work, then try to change the "Installation type" from "Restore" to "Install".

> **NuGet 3.2**
>
> With NuGet 3.2, the following commands have been tested to work:
>
> Config
>
> Delete
> Help
> Install
> List
> Push
> SetApiKey
> Sources
> Spec

Refer to this link for details: [NuGet Compatibility](http://docs.nuget.org/consume/Compatibility).

Comment: pointing the nuget item at the `packages.config` file did work as long as I added the argument `-PackageDirectory /mydirectory/packages`. The next brick wall I hit though was that the first thing Xamarin.iOS build work item tries to do is restore nuget packages which fails

Comment: automated builds and continuous integration is a great thing, but due to the lack of documentation of configuring a Xamarin project from beginning to end it makes it 100x more difficult. Its attractive for Xamarin developers to implement due to trying to control the 3 different targets. but due to the lack of documentation/guides/walkthroughs on how to configure I just feel like its not worth the effort. My two cents

Comment: @user1 Do you mean the package restore occurs again when the Xamarin build start?

Comment: Yes it occurs again when Xamarin.iOS tries to build and fails because I can't feed it the `-packageDirectory` argument at this stage. My solution does enable nuget package restore so that may be it but that is to make it easier for developers to get up and running straight from source control

Comment: @user1 Seems you are using "MSBuild-Integrated Package Restore", however it should works with Mono. Please check the settings against this link: https://docs.nuget.org/consume/package-restore/msbuild-integrated. And can you also check your project file to see if there is any nuget restore task included in it. The task section is the same as this link: https://docs.nuget.org/Consume/package-restore/team-build

Comment: I have migrated my solution from using MSBuild-Integrated package restore to Automatic package Restore using [this link](http://docs.nuget.org/consume/package-restore/migrating-to-automatic-package-restore). I then added the Nuget build step you mentioned and pointed it to the packages.config instead of solution. which works. I then get to the build Xamarin.iOS step and get the error `/usr/local/bin/nuget restore mydir...
Cannot determine the packages folder to restore NuGet packages. Please specify either -PackagesDirectory or -SolutionDirectory.`

Comment: Xamarin.iOS build using VSTS online. Is it actually possible?

Comment: @user1 Can you share the screenshot for the settings of "Build Xamarin.iOS solution" step?

Comment: I have uploaded a screenshot [here](http://imgur.com/KHYZMF8). It's all pretty standard settings

Comment: @user1 I check the screenshot, you are entering the project file in "Solution" area. Try to change it to solution file. The description for that tab: "Relative path from repo root of the Xamarin.iOS solution to build.".

Comment: @user1 And here is an instruction for how to build Xamarin.iOS build: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/vs/alm/build/apps/xamarin#DefineyourXamarin_iOSbuild

Comment: I changed it to the solution and we are back to the original error explained  in the question. because as you pointed out in this answer nuget restore does not work with solution files. I need a way to turn off Nuget restore when building Xamarin.iOS solutions / projects

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar issue. My log said:

```
Unable to find version '2.1.0' of package 'Acr.Support'.
[error]Error: /usr/local/bin/nuget failed with return code: 1
```

After some digging in the logs I tried to restore the nuget packages on my local mac. I opened the terminal and typed :

`sudo cd /usr/local/bin`

`[enter password]`

Your nuget executable should be located there.
I executed:

`nuget`

To see my nuget version, which was 2.12.0.0
I noticed that this is an old version so I updated it by:

`sudo su
[enter password]
nuget update -self`

I noticed that it updated to 3.4.4 rtm final, I started my Visual Studio Online flow again and it worked! Hopefully this helps anyone.

Comment: Found my own question through google for a similar issue (the one you describe) and this answer helped me solve my problem